# How to correctly use AmazonDynamoDBLockClient in a spring boot project?

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, localhost, locking

I am trying to acquire a lock using the AmazonDynamoDBLockClient, with DynamoDb running on localhost.
But i am getting NPE saying `Cannot invoke "software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.AttributeValue.s()" because "ownerName" is null`

Following is the project structure

Dependency in the POM

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
 <artifactId>dynamodb-lock-client</artifactId>
 <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Beans configuration

```
@Bean
public DynamoDbClient dynamoDbClient(){
  return DynamoDbClient.builder()
         .endpointOverride(URI.create("http://localhost:8000"))
         .build();
}

@Bean
public AmazonDynamoDBLockClient amazonDynamoDBLockClient(){
 return new AmazonDynamoDBLockClient(AmazonDynamoDBLockClientOptions
    .builder(dynamoDbClient(), "table-name")
    .withPartitionKeyName("partition-key-name")
    .withOwnerName("owner-name") // I have put "app" here
    .withTimeUnit(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .withLeaseDuration(10L)
    .withHeartbeatPeriod(3L)
    .withCreateHeartbeatBackgroundThread(true)
    .build());
}
```

Acquire Lock method

```
public Optional<LockItem> acquireLock(){
  return amazonDynamoDBLockClient.tryAcquireLock(AcquireLockOptions.builder("partitionKey").build();
}
```

I would appreciate any insights on the problem.